# How do I fix TypeError unhashable type: 'rqm__Cell' -> (Auto-generated class)

Tags: python-3.x, python-jsonschema

I am using python-json-schema-objects to autogenerate classes from a schema. I am trying to fill in an array with objects already generated.

But I am getting this error -

> TypeError unhashable type: 'rqm__Cell'

My question and the error is pretty similar to the one posted here
https://github.com/cwacek/python-jsonschema-objects/issues/126

This is the schema

```
"rqm__RatType": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "GSM",
    "CDMA"
  ]
},
"rqm__ChannelBandwidth": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "BW_1_4_MHZ",
    "BW_3_MHZ",
  ]
},
"rqm__Cell": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "rat": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/rqm__RatType"
    },
    "bandwidth": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/rqm__ChannelBandwidth"
    }
  }
},
"rqm__CellSet": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "cellsToDeploy": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/rqm__Cell"
      },
      "minItems": 0,
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  }
},
```

The code I am using is

```
import python_jsonschema_objects as pjs
schema = {}
schema['Rqm'] = 'rqm.json'
builder = pjs.ObjectBuilder(schema['Rqm'])
ns = builder.build_classes()
Cell = ns.RqmCell
CellSet = ns.RqmCellset
cellSet = None
GSMCell = Cell(rat='GSM', bandwidth='BW_1_4_MHZ')
cellSet = CellSet(cellsToDeploy=[GSMCell])
```

At the last line I get this error

> TypeError unhashable type: 'rqm__Cell'

Many Thanks for any type of lead

Comment: It is because of `"uniqueItems": true`. It looks like the library converts the child elements, in this case `rqm__Cell`s, to a `set` and checks if the length is unchanged. Weirdly enough, setting `uniqueItems` to `false` is not enough, it must be removed completely, as they're testing for `not None` and not `true`.

Comment: @Jeppe Then how can we make sure that all the documents (items) in the array are unique?

Comment: I'm not sure - perhaps you should open an issue on [github](https://github.com/cwacek/python-jsonschema-objects). I already created a pull-request fixing the `uniqueItems: false` problem. The solution could perhaps be to test for uniqueness differently or attach a hash-function to the generated classes, iterating the properties defined by your schema - but frankly I'm not very experienced with object-hashing to do so. Or I guess the issue you linked may be the same.

Comment: There appears to be a fix now, maybe you can test it out: https://github.com/cwacek/python-jsonschema-objects/pull/168